# How to check if data attribute exist with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if an HTML5 data attribute exists using plain javascript.
I have tried the below code snippet, but it doesn't work.

```
if(object.getAttribute("data-params")==="undefined") {
   //data-attribute doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: `if(typeof obj["data-attribute"] !== "undefined"){ // code here }`

Answer (score 161, accepted):

[`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) returns `null` or empty string if the attribute does not exist.

You'd use [`Element.hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute):

```
if (!object.hasAttribute("data-example-param")) {
    // data attribute doesn't exist
}
```

or [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (see also: [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)):

```
if (!("exampleParam" in object.dataset)) {
    // data attribute doesn't exist
}
```

or even

```
if (!object.getAttribute("data-example-param")) {
    // data attribute doesn't exist or is empty
}
```

Comment: Why as the selected answer has this been marked down?

Comment: Note that the casing and the handling of dashes in the attribute name `data-example-param` is different for `dataset` then for `hasAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 7):

Checking against null also yielded the solution.

```
if (object.getAttribute("data-example-param") === null) {
//data attribute doesn't exist
 }else{
 //data attribute exists
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could as well just use the dataset API.

[**HTMLElement.dataset**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

> The HTMLElement.dataset read-only property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

Sadly this will not work in IE10 but i am pretty sure that there is a shim out there somewhere.

Here is an example

```js
var containerData  = document.querySelector('#container').dataset,
    contentData  = document.querySelector('#content').dataset;

// Check if dataset is empty or not.
console.log(Object.keys(containerData).length === 0);
console.log(Object.keys(contentData).length === 0);

// Check for specific data
if (containerData.hasOwnProperty('bar')) {
  console.log(containerData.bar);
}

// Here is the dataset
console.log(containerData);
```

```html
<div id="container" data-foo="bar" data-bar="foo">
  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted doesn't won't work as you expect, what you're doing here is checking if the attribute-value of the named attribute (`"data-params"`) is equal to `"undefined"`, which will return `true` only if the attribute is `data-params="undefined"`.

```
if (object.getAttribute("data-params") === "undefined") {
   // the "data-params" attribute-value is exactly "undefined"
   // note that `getAttribute()` is a 
}
```

What I suspect you want to do is:

```
var typeOfObjectAttribute = typeof object.getAttribute("data-params");

if (typeOfObjectAttribute === null || typeOfObjectAttribute === "") {
   // data-params attribute doesn't exist on that Node.
}
```

Note that – according Mozilla Developer Network (at the reference for `Element.getAttribute()`, below) – states that:

> `getAttribute()` returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be `null` or `""` (the empty string)…

It's also worth noting that `getAttribute()` is a method of the Element nodes, rather than generic objects.

Incidentally, you could also use the following approach (again, testing that the attribute is *not* set):

```
// here we look to see if the 'params' key is present in the
// HTMLElement.dataset object of the element, and then invert
// that result using the '!' operator, to check that the
// attribute *isn't* present:
if (!('params' in document.getElementById('elementID').dataset)) {
    // the data-params attribute is not present.
}
```

References:

- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked well for me was this.

```js
if(typeof object.dataset.sheet === "undefined") {
  console.log('Data attribute does not exist');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even more simple:

```
if (object.dataset.sheet !== undefined) {
  // the "data-sheet" attribute exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To see if a given HTML5 element has a specific custom HTML5 `data-*` attribute, simply examine the element's `dataset`.

A `dataset` is a `DOMStringMap` **object** so you can use the `hasOwnProperty()` method:

```
if (element.dataset.hasOwnProperty('params')) {

  [... CODE HERE...]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
if(typeof object.getAttribute("data-params") === "undefined") {
   console.log('data-attribute doesn't exist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cang do just falsy value check

```
if(!object.getAttribute("data-params")) {
   //data-attribute doesn't exist
}
```

cause `getAttribute` can return null or empty string

also you can use `object.hasAttribute("data-params")` just to check if attribute exists

Answer (score 0):

If anyone landed here knowing what data attribute they are looking for then you can check if it exists with

HTML:

```
<input id="your-element" data-type="something">
```

JS:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#your-element');
if( element.dataset.type === 'something'){
// Do something
}
```

Of course the `type` in `data-type` in the example above is a custom name, data attributes can have any name such as `data-cats` or `data-dogs` etc.. ... ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `matches()` method and the selector works the same way as a query selector does

Comment: On Stackoverflow you are supposed to provide context on your answer.