# Javascript - show hidden div if 'checked' is present on a div element (not a checkbox element)

Tags: javascript

I have something that is likely simple, but I'm struggling :/

I am trying to show a hidden div if the parent element is 'checked' (it is not a checkbox, but we're adding checked to the div if it's clicked on). Here's a screenshot of what the checked looks like in my local environment (screenshot attached).

Here's the code with the div 'checked' and I suspect this should make the hidden div show, but it is not.

Here's the guide I'm following, and the code example below: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp

```js
var checkBox = document.getElementById("accordionButton");
// Get the output text
var text = document.getElementById("accordionContent");

// If the element is checked, display the accordion content
if (checkBox.checked == true){
  text.style.display = "block";
} else {
  text.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="accordionButton" checked> <!-- here is where when check is true, I want to show accordion content -->
  <p>
    <span>Migrate from another platform</span>
  </p>
  <div id="accordionContent">
    option 1 option 2 option 3 option 4
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `if (checkBox.checked == true)` should be `if (checkBox.hasAttribute('checked'))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if data attribute exist with plain javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249997/how-to-check-if-data-attribute-exist-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: Anyway, as `<div>`s do not natively have a `checked` attribute, it would be preferable to have something like `<div data-checked="true">` and check for `if (checkBox.dataset.checked === true)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. I tried various combinations from your feedback, but they didn't have the effect I was looking for.

Here's what I ultimately ended up with. If there's a better way to write this please let me know. This works in the live environment where the checkbox attribute can be toggled.

I appreciate your help!

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  
  var button = document.getElementById("accordionButton"); // Get the clickable div
  var text = document.getElementById("accordionContent"); // Get the hidden div

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (button.getAttribute("checked") === null) {
    text.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "block";
  }

});
```

```css
#accordionContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordionButton" checked>
  <p>
    <span>Migrate from another platform</span>
  </p>
  <div id="accordionContent">
    option 1 option 2 option 3 option 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are adding the attribute `checked` rather than a class attribute (e.g. `class="checked"`)? If there is no particular constraint, I would suggest a different approach which, IMHO, provides a better separation of concerns; for example, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1wbukvg8/ (the code can be simplified, if you do not need to support multiple accordions in the same page)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is. I'm targeting someone else's code that's built into a component, otherwise I would definitely change it.