# QuerySelector to get Data-Attri Value

Tags: javascript, json

`document.querySelectorAll(".row__seat--selected");`

Shows a NodeList of 5 elements(<div........>) , I want to take only the **"data-tooltip" value** in the JSON

[image: View The Error Here]

```js
function buytickets() {
  const tick = document.querySelectorAll(".row__seat--selected");
  console.log(tick);
  const myJSON = JSON.stringify(tick);
  console.log(myJSON);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R1"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R2"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R3"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R4"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R5"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R6"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R7"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R8"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R9"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R10"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R11"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R12"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R13"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R14"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R15"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R16"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R17"></div>
  <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="R18"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What JSON? Why are you stringifying a list of elements?

Comment: Please post your code as a snippet rather than in image. Your code has no mention of your data-tooltip attribute.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: The Values of the data-tooltip that i have selected.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you do anything with that attribute in your script. Are you familiar with `element.getAttribute()`?

Comment: I want to Stringify the attribute. And use it

Comment: This is a table of 18 seats, When I clicked a seat,It  takes the class active, and i want with a button get all the actived seats infos.(attribute) in a string of json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250073/989920 might be of help

Comment: ok thank you,but basic it is how to get the ids of a selected button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that by this way

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-tooltip]").forEach(el =>{
console.log(el.dataset.tooltip)
})
```

and to get specific one

```
console.log(document.querySelector("[data-tooltip='R18']"))
```